# Cómo Optimizar código, (meses del año)

Tags: java

B dias!!!
Estoy intentando hacer un programa sobre los meses del año, de tal manera que al ingresar un número, devuelva su mes correspondiente y lo he conseguido, pero como soy novato, me da la impresión que mi código se puede optimizar, aunque no sé como.
Alguna idea??

```java
int num1=0;
        boolean error=true;

        do {
                 try {
                System.out.print("Ingrese un Número Para ver su Mes Correspondiente: "); 
                num1= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                error=false;
                 }//end try
                 catch (Exception er) {
                     System.out.println("ERROR!");
             }//end catch

        }while (num1<1 || num1>12 || error==true);


        String mes="a";
        if (num1==1) {              
            mes="Enero";
        }
        if (num1==2) {
             mes="Enero.";
        }
        if (num1==3) {
             mes="Marzo.";
        }
        if (num1==4) {
             mes="Abril.";
        }
        if (num1==5) {
             mes="Mayo.";
        }
        if (num1==6) {
             mes="Junio.";
        }
        if (num1==7) {
            mes="Julio";
        }
        if (num1==8) {
            mes="Agosto.";
        }
        if (num1==9) {
            mes="Septiembre.";
        }
        if (num1==10) {
            mes="Octubre.";
        }
        if (num1==11) {
            mes="Noviembre.";
        }
        if (num1==12) {
            mes="Diciembre.";
        }

        System.out.print("El Mes seleccionado es: "+mes);
```

Había pensado en un array bidimensional, pero tampoco se como enfocarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si te sirve de ayuda, yo habŕia hecho algo como esto:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 

public class Meses {

    public static void main(final String[] args)  {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        final String[] meses = {
            "Enero", 
            "Febrero", 
            "Marzo", 
            "Abril", 
            "Mayo",
            "Junio",
            "Julio",
            "Agosto",
            "Septiembre",
            "Octubre",
            "Noviembre",
            "Diciembre"
        };

        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Ingrese un Número Para ver su Mes, ó 0 para finalizar: "); 
                int mes = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                if (mes == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if ((mes > 0) && (mes <= meses.length))  {
                        System.out.println("\n=======> " + meses[mes -1] + " <=======\n ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Por favor, presta un poco de atención");
                    }
                }
            } catch (final Exception er) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!" + er);
                continue;
            }

        } while (true);
    }  
}
```

De esta forma, en el hipotético caso de que algún día se decidiera añadir, o eliminar, un mes del calendario, sólo habria que actualizar la lista para que el programa siguiera funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Gracias!!!   Máquina!!!